# Merge [synchronized] into [synchronization]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I'd like to propose we make [synchronized](/questions/tagged/synchronized)x[282](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronized) a synonym of [synchronization](/questions/tagged/synchronization)x[2464](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization).